# Is there a benefit to embedding ActionScript in MXML when developing Flex apps?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I always thought that separating the UI from the logic is the way to go like the use of class files in Flash CS3/CS4 or MVC in web frameworks but recently there are plenty of examples and posts using ActionScript embedded in MXML.

Is there a benefit to doing this? Am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get too caught up on the "rules" of MVC and the like. Ultimately you want your code to be setup in such a way that it will minimize the impact/churn of future changes. It's less important "where" the code is and more important what and how it's interacting with other code. I see far to many people take a simple component like a login screen and make models, view, controllers, view helpers, service facades, etc. It ends up being like 75+ lines of code for something that should have been about 20. It also spreads the code amoungst a bunch of files rather than one. So in the end, you've made maintenace hard, not easy. I'm not arguing for ignoring design patterns, but rather being practical about it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, there's not much of a difference whether you write a component in ActionScript + MXML, or solely in Actionscript.  Personally, if I'm writing something that's layout heavy with a little logic, I'll do it in MXML.  Conversely, if it's code heavy and has little layout, I'll write it in Actionscript.

I suppose you could always separate the view and model, but then you have more files to maintain.  Sometimes it makes sense, but I have yet to see a compelling reason to do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I go by a few simple rules:

- If a bit of code is just a single short line and it isn't something you can reuse elsewhere -- mere glue code -- put it directly in the MXML tag.
- If it's too long to fit comfortably in the MXML tag or it is something multiple components in that MXML file can use, put it in a function in a Script tag within the same file, and call the function from the MXML tag(s).
- Everything else -- full classes, large functions, things used by multiple MXML files -- goes in a separate .as file.  This includes single-LOC methods that are part of a larger class, as opposed to the standalone functions the other rules cover.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Erich Douglass, to a point. Generally, if I can do the layout with MXML it's just easier to maintain. I mean, who wants to write all that crap in a createChildren override if you don't have to? Besides, the MXML is easier to read.

Whatever you do, though, remember that if you are merely calling a separate script file for an MXML component (Foo.mxml calls Foo.as for its ActionScript) you are losing the code highlighting feature that helps you work between the MXML and the ActionScript. I like to keep them both in the same place, so when I click on an ID in an MXML element I can see at a glance where it's being referenced in the AS.